# Battery Health in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery

I am experiencing low battery timing on my Laptop so i wanted to ask if my battery is fine? output of `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1`
 :

```
native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               13-42
  model:                OA04041
  serial:               02019 10/08/2014
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 28 Feb 2017 08:33:11 PM PKT (24 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    energy:              7.178 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         24.2424 Wh
    energy-full-design:  24.2424 Wh
    energy-rate:         25.826 W
    voltage:             16.118 V
    time to full:        39.6 minutes
    percentage:          30%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
  History (charge):
    1488295991  30.000  charging
    1488295961  29.000  charging
    1488295931  28.000  charging
  History (rate):
    1488295991  25.826  charging
    1488295961  25.708  charging
    1488295931  25.145  charging

srseven@srseven-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               13-42
  model:                OA04041
  serial:               02019 10/08/2014
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 28 Feb 2017 08:35:31 PM PKT (1 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    energy:              8.1992 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         24.2424 Wh
    energy-full-design:  24.2424 Wh
    energy-rate:         26.2996 W
    voltage:             16.286 V
    time to empty:       18.7 minutes
    percentage:          34%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
  History (charge):
    1488296111  34.000  charging
    1488296081  33.000  charging
    1488296051  32.000  charging
    1488296021  31.000  charging
  History (rate):
    1488296130  26.300  discharging
    1488296111  25.708  charging
    1488296081  25.930  charging
    1488296051  26.018  charging
    1488296021  26.226  charging
```

is this fine?

Answer (score 1):

A google search of "specifications for vendor: 13-42 model: OA04041 battery" took me straight to the HP support page for your laptop

Two clicks later:
"Troubleshooting the notebook battery"
http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-G42-Notebook-PC-series/4346229/model/5085769/document/c00259897/

There's been a recall of some of those batteries, you should take a look.